# An Issue with merging columns based on the row ID in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, mariadb, group-concat, subquery

I need to merge the `comment` columns based on the row with the column name `ID` I had a SQL query in order to merge replies to the commented posts considering count values to the replied posts i.e, `comment_counts`. I require to display nested comments within a single thread from the news feed post.
Below is my SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ft.ID as ID, ft.userid, ft.content, ft.timestamp, ft.comments as comment_counts, ftc.comment, ftc.timestamp as comment_timestamp, uq.username, uq.avatar 
FROM users uq, feed_item ft 
LEFT JOIN feed_item_comment ftc ON ftc.postid = ft.ID 
LEFT JOIN user_friends uf ON uf.friendid = ftc.userid 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = uf.friendid WHERE uq.ID = ft.userid AND ft.userid
IN 
(SELECT u.ID FROM users u WHERE u.ID 
    IN (SELECT uf.friendid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.userid = '".$this->user->info->ID."') 
        OR 
        u.ID 
        IN (SELECT uf.userid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.friendid = '".$this->user->info->ID."') 
        OR
        u.ID = '".$this->user->info->ID."'
) ORDER BY ft.ID DESC, ftc.timestamp DESC
```

**Actual Result:**

This was the result obtained from the above query

```
ID  userid      content                 timestamp   comment_counts  comment         comment_timestamp       username        avatar   
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

3   1           This is manju           13:12:31        2           manju comment   13:17:31                manju           1698862132.png   
3   1           This is manju           13:12:31        2           new cmt         14:00:15                manju           1698862132.png   
2   14          How are you doing?      13:06:42        2           Fine            15:00:15                Nishanth        default.png   
2   14          How are you doing?      13:06:42        2           Not Good        15:05:10                Nishanth        default.png   
1   14          How are you?            14:07:00        2           Look Good       20:00:00                Nishanth        default.png   
1   14          How are you?            14:07:00        2           So I'm!         20:10:00                Nishanth        default.png
```

*For the single news feed post with multiple comments displaying in separate feeds with nested comments. 
Although nested comments were displaying repeatedly. But with separate news feed thread*

**Expected Result**:

```
ID  userid  content             timestamp   comment_counts  comment1        comment1_timestamp  comment2    comment2_timestamp  username    avatar   
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

3   1       This is manju       13:12:31        2           manju comment   13:17:31            new cmt     14:00:15            manju       1698862132.png   
2   14      How are you doing?  13:06:42        2           Fine            15:00:15            Not Good    15:05:10            Nishanth    default.png   
1   14      How are you?        14:07:00        2           Look Good       20:00:00            So I'm!     20:10:00            Nishanth    default.png
```

*I need to display only nested comments (not repeated) with only one single news post as a thread 

For instance for single news feed with the message "How are you doing" as I have commented with "Fine" and "Not Good"  

For the post "How are you doing" it is repeating twice. Because I have commented twice with the text "Fine" and "Not Good"  

How should I need to prevent nested comments repeated twice within the single news feed as a thread.*

By using `GROUP_CONCAT(ftc.comment) as replies`

```
ID userid   content         timestamp     comment_counts   comment      comment_timestamp   username   avatar           replies  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

1   14      How are you?    14:07:00            2           Look Good   20:00:00            Nishanth   default.png   Look Good,Fine,Not Good,manju comment,new cmt,Look...
```

---

### Complete Database with a query:

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71b68/3/0)

By using `GROUP_CONCAT(ftc.comment)` as replies

```
ID userid   content         timestamp     comment_counts   comment      comment_timestamp   username   avatar           replies  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

1   14      How are you?    14:07:00            2           Look Good   20:00:00            Nishanth   default.png   Look Good,Fine,Not Good,manju comment,new cmt,Look...
```

***How am I suppose to write the SQL query in order to merge the rows from results obtained in order to get the desired/expected results?***

Comment: You may want to read up on pivot tables. Although what you want to do isn't a typical pivot, you're still trying to turn rows into columns, and that's what pivot does.

Comment: what is your mysql version @nishanth

Comment: MariaDB Server version: 10.1.36 @fa06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below using row_number() and conditional aggregation

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7a3847b43e4486836285bc4e0cc83c1b)

```
select id, userid,content,timestamp,comment_count,
min(case when seq=1 then comment end) as comment1,
min(case when seq=1 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime1,
min(case when seq=2 then comment end) as comment2,
min(case when seq=2 then comment_timestamp end) as commenttime2
from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by id,userid order by comment_timestamp) as seq from 
(SELECT DISTINCT ft.ID as ID, ft.userid, ft.content, ft.timestamp, ft.comments as comment_count, ftc.comment, ftc.timestamp as comment_timestamp, uq.username, uq.avatar FROM users uq,
feed_item ft 
LEFT JOIN feed_item_comment ftc ON ftc.postid = ft.ID
LEFT JOIN user_friends uf ON uf.friendid = ftc.userid 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = uf.friendid WHERE uq.ID = ft.userid AND ft.userid
IN 
(SELECT u.ID FROM users u WHERE u.ID 
IN (SELECT uf.friendid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.userid = 1) 
OR u.ID IN 
(SELECT uf.userid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.friendid = 1) 
OR
u.ID = 1
)ORDER BY ft.ID DESC, ftc.timestamp DESC)X)Y
group by id, userid,content,timestamp,comment_count
```

Comment: I appreciate your dedicated efforts. The query is working perfectly fine. But
to the Dynamic values for the replies & timestamp to the posts i.e for comment_count > 2. How am I supposed to approach to your query
Since I have appended (7, 2, 14, 'Not Bad After All your efforts!', '08:13:10', 0, 0, 0); to the `feed_item_comment` table
[Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ef5f82f345d1d4dcd871036535d3d468)

Comment: For the `feed_item_comment`with `comment` as a reply value =  `Not Good` for the posted `content` value =  `How are you doing?` from the `feed_item` table It should be displayed appending to the next column as a part of dynamic replies to the commented post. Thereby creating a new column itself automatically to the replies to the post. Will, you could assist me in doing so?!

Comment: @Nishanthॐ, can you please add it to your expected output

Comment: Sure just a minute

Comment: @Nishanthॐ does maria db your versionsupport pivot?

Comment: Since I need to run this on the hosting server running MySQL. No need to bother about wheter it works on localhost or not!

Comment: @Nishanthॐ, you need a dynamic pivot for your query and that's why I am asking wherther pivot is supporting by your version or not and I've no idea how to dynamic pivot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181868/discussion-between-nishanth--and-fa06).